# C#, Asynchronous sockets Server/Client, StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, stack-overflow

I'm writing an asynchronous server and client with C#. I took sample code from MSDN, modified and made it to send and receive messages several times. I tried to connect 5 and more clients to server and it worked but on 98th iteration each **client** throws an exception StackOverflow. Can anybody explain me why I get this error? I've read in MSDN that my problem in infinite loops but I don't understand how can I change my code and write it without loops.

This server-client should be used in multiplayer racing game and I need to send and receive the coordinates of each player several times per second. How can I do it without infinite loops?

Here is my code:

SERVER:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;


public class Server
{
    Socket main_tcp_Sock;
    private static ManualResetEvent acceptDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent recvDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent closeDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    //int cl_Count = 0;
    List<StateObject> connection_List = new List<StateObject>();
    private static String response = String.Empty;


    public class StateObject
    {
        public Socket current_Socket = null;
        public byte[] data = new byte[256];
        public string id = string.Empty;
    }
    public Server()
    {
        Server_Start();
    }

    public void Server_Start()
    {

        //Creating socket
        main_tcp_Sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                  SocketType.Stream,
                                  ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 2000);
        //Bind socket
        try
        {
            main_tcp_Sock.Bind(ipLocal);
            Console.WriteLine("Server has started successfully!");


            //Start listening
            main_tcp_Sock.Listen(100);
            while (true)
            {

                acceptDone.Reset();
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");

                //AsyncAccept
                main_tcp_Sock.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(On_Connect), main_tcp_Sock);
                acceptDone.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine("\nPress any button to continue...\n\n");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

    }

    public void On_Connect(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {

        try
        {

            Socket listener = (Socket)asyn.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(asyn);
            acceptDone.Set();

            StateObject connection = new StateObject();
            connection.current_Socket = handler;

            if (!connection_List.Contains(connection))
            {
                lock (connection_List)
                {
                    connection_List.Add(connection);
                    connection.id = "00" + connection_List.Count.ToString() + " ";
                 }
            }
            recvDone.Reset();
            Receive(connection.current_Socket);
            recvDone.WaitOne();

            sendDone.Reset();
            Send(connection.current_Socket, response);
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            closeDone.Reset();
            Socket_Close(connection.current_Socket);
            closeDone.WaitOne();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("On_Connect Error: {0}", e.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    public void Receive(Socket handler)
        {
        try{
            StateObject connection = new StateObject();
            connection.current_Socket = handler;
            connection.current_Socket.BeginReceive(connection.data, 0, connection.data.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(On_Receive), connection);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

    }
    public void On_Receive(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        string content = "";
        string temp = "";
        StateObject connection = (StateObject)asyn.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = connection.current_Socket;
        int size = handler.EndReceive(asyn);


        Console.WriteLine("ConnID from receive: " + connection.id);
        if (size > 0)
        {
            temp += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(connection.data);
        }
        if (temp.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
        {

            content += temp.Substring(0, temp.IndexOf("\0"));
            Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \nMessage: {1}", content.Length, content);

            lock (connection_List)
            {
                foreach (StateObject conn in connection_List)
                {
                    if (conn != connection)
                    {
                    content.Insert(0, connection.id);
                    response = content;
                   }

                }
            }
            recvDone.Set();
        }
        else
        {
            handler.BeginReceive(connection.data, 0, connection.data.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(On_Receive), connection);
        }

    }

    public void Send(Socket handler, String message)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        handler.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(On_Send), handler);

    }

    public void On_Send(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            Socket handler = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
            state.current_Socket = handler;
            int size = state.current_Socket.EndSend(result);
            if (size > 0)
            {
                sendDone.Set();
            }

            else state.current_Socket.BeginSend(state.data, 0, state.data.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                new AsyncCallback(On_Send), state);
            Console.WriteLine("Bytes sent to client: {0}", size);

            sendDone.Set();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("On_Send e, error: " + e.ToString());
             Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
    public void Socket_Close(Socket sock)
    {
        sock.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 3);

        sock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        sock.Close();
        closeDone.Set();
    }

}
```

And client:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;

// State object for receiving data from remote device.
public class StateObject
{
    // Client socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousClient
{
    public static int count = 0;

    // The port number for the remote device.
    private const int port = 2000;
    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent closeDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    // The response from the remote device.
    private static String response = String.Empty;

    private static void StartClient()
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.

        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Start(client, remoteEP);

    }


    public static void Start(Socket client, EndPoint remoteEP)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                /*if (count >= 30)
                {

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    if (count >= 100)
                    {
                        count = 0;
                        Thread.Sleep(1500);
                    }
                }*/

                Console.WriteLine(count);
                connectDone.Reset();
                client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
                connectDone.WaitOne();


                // Send test data to the remote device.
                sendDone.Reset();
                Send(client, "Some text and <EOF>");
                sendDone.WaitOne();

                // Receive the response from the remote device.
                receiveDone.Reset();
                Receive(client);
                receiveDone.WaitOne();

                // Write the response to the console.
                Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);

                // Release the socket.
                closeDone.Reset();
                Socket_Close(client);
                closeDone.WaitOne();

                ++count;
            }

        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint remote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);

            Start(sock, remote);

        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                       SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint remote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);

            Start(sock, remote);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Signal that the connection has been made.
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey(true);

        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                // Get the rest of the data.
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                }
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey(true);

        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {
        try
        {
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    public static void Socket_Close(Socket sock)
    {
        try
        {
            sock.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 3);
            sock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sock.Close();
            closeDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {

        StartClient();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm new in C#. Pls, help somebody.

Comment: instead of listening in while loop, you can use timer too.

Comment: Thank you for response, I'll read about timer in C#, but could you explain me what is the difference? Why do loops bring to Stackoverflow but timers don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while (true)` will never stop... you must do something like `while (foo) { if (somecondition) foo=false }`

EDIT: Maybe this tutorial will help

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_date_time/timeroutines/article.php/c7763

snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

class myApp
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler( DisplayTimeEvent );
    myTimer.Interval = 1000;
    myTimer.Start();

    while ( Console.Read() != 'q' )
    {
        ;    // do nothing...
    }
  }

  public static void DisplayTimeEvent( object source, ElapsedEventArgs e )
  {
      Console.Write("\r{0}", DateTime.Now);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. This loop will stop when player exits the game, but it should work while he plays because it is supposed to send his own coordinates and receive coordinates of other players several times per second. Is this impossible with loops? Are timers better? Why? I just want to understand it. Thank you.

Comment: yes... a `while` loop will block the thread (nothing will happen until it exits)... you should set up a timer to check every N milliseconds... I could provide some ActionScript equivalent code (not a C# guy)

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite my code using timers but it doesn't work. I'll try more. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! Timer solved my problem. Now I have other problems but they are not suitable for this topic.

Comment: good to know! maybe you could mark this answer as accepted since it helped you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

A stack is a Last-In-First-Out queue. When you make a function call, the state relevant to the function you are in (e.g. local variables) needs to be saved so that the programme can process the called function. When the called function returns, the state of the calling function must be restored, so it is retrieved from the stack. In normal programmes, the stack grows as you invoke more and more deeply nested functions, but then shrinks again as they return.

Of course, the stack is not limitless, and in fact is usually allocated a fixed amount of memory, so if you have a programme where the level of nested function calls keeps growing, eventually the stack will be full, and you'll receive a stack overflow exception.

The easiest way to demonstrate this is to write a function that always calls itself recursively. The following will always create a stack overflow:

```
private void blowTheStack(){
  blowTheStack();
}
```

Of course, we can also write recursive programmes without this problem:

```
private void doSomethingUseful(){
  if (!terminatingConditionReached()){
    doSomethingUseful();
  }
}
```

and this is a very powerful technique. The trick with writing such code is to get your terminating condition right!

When this all takes place in one function, the logic is easy to see, however, you can also have similar logic where one function calls another, which calls another, which calls the first function.

When you're working with event handling code, it gets worse, because the function calls don't look like function calls any more. Let's say one function triggers a condition which triggers an event handler, and the event handler triggers some code which calls the first function, you would also have cyclic function invocations, and if the terminating condition isn't right, you would get a stack overflow.

Anyway - I just want to +1 the question because it's about a Stack Overflow!